# Problem with my function ($IterationLimit::itlim: Iteration limit of 4096 exceeded.)

Tags: functions, warning-messages

I defined a function that only depends on one coordinate and it is giving an error. My code for now looks like this:

```
n = 4;
coord = {t, r, θ, φ};
Subscript[φ, 0][r_] := Subscript[φ, 0][r];
Subscript[Λ, 0][r_] := 
  Subscript[Λ, 0][r];
δφ[t_, r_] := δφ[t, r];
δΛ[t_, r_] := δΛ[t, r];
metric = {{-E^(2 εδφ[t, r] + 
        2 Subscript[φ, 0][r]), 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
    E^(2 εδΛ[t, r] + 
       2 Subscript[Λ, 0][r]), 0, 0}, {0, 0, r^2, 
    0}, {0, 0, 0, r^2 Sin θ}};
metric // MatrixForm
```

The error that appears is

```
$IterationLimit::itlim: Iteration limit of 4096 exceeded.
```

[image]

How can I rewrite my function so the code works.
I've programmed in other languages, but I'm new to Mathematica. If there's anything else I can rewrite in a better way, I'd appreciate the help as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit 3: This `Sin θ` should be `Sin[θ]`. I just spotted that, so please adopt this in the rest of the reply as you copy and paste in your notebook!!!

The commands

```
Subscript[φ, 0][r_] := Subscript[φ, 0][r];
Subscript[Λ, 0][r_] := Subscript[Λ, 0][r]
```

cause trouble. Quite frankly there's a straightforward way to go about it. We call `Subscript[φ, 0][r]` the very simple `φ0[r]` and likewise for the `Lambda` we have `Λ0[r]`

Now we run

```
n = 4;
coord = {t, r, θ, φ};
metric = {{-E^(2 εδφ[t, r] + 2 φ0[r]), 0, 0,
     0}, {0, 
    E^(2 εδΛ[t, r] + 
       2 Λ0[r]), 0, 0}, {0, 0, r^2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
    r^2 Sin θ}};
metric // MatrixForm
```

[image: metric]

Edit 1: This seems like some sort of metric perturbation, so just a tip. In the way that it is written, this `εδφ[t, r]` is a single thing. If you want the small $\epsilon$-expansion and the $\delta \phi$ to be the perturbation the you should have spaces; `ε δφ[t,r]`. This is $\epsilon$ times whatever.

Edit 2: if for your own reasons you want to work with subscripts you can just execute

```
n = 4;
coord = {t, r, θ, φ};
metric = {{-E^(2 εδφ[t, r] + 
        2 Subscript[φ, 0][r]), 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
    E^(2 εδΛ[t, r] + 
       2 Subscript[Λ, 0][r]), 0, 0}, {0, 0, r^2, 
    0}, {0, 0, 0, r^2 Sin θ}};
metric // MatrixForm
```

[image: metric2]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, I'm working with a perturbed metric because I want to calculate the Christofell symbols referring to it and then the covariant derivative of a given vector (if you know any simpler commands I'd appreciate it). Anyway, I tried the changes you mentioned and only \Lambda still gives an error. Could it be because it is not a coordinate? Or could it be the lack of some package? I have just downloaded diffgeo.

Comment: @IsabellaNunes You do not need any packages to do Christoffel, Riemann, Ricci, etc in my opinion. The best approach for me is the code that you can easily manipulate, and not a package. If you can update the OP so I can see what's going on I am happy to help! Just add the new code that is giving you trouble or a screenshot

Comment: Ok! I added the screenshot to the question.

Comment: @IsabellaNunes if you see the color of $\delta\Lambda$ is black, while the other are blue. It means that from a previous command, you have performed that problematic definition I mentioned in my answer. Can you please, `Quit[]` and take my code and run it in a fresh kernel? And let me know how it goes

Comment: It worked now. Thank you so much for your patience and clarity in your answers!

Comment: @IsabellaNunes you're very welcome :-) Glad I helped